# Memory Stream Byte Array vs ImageConverter Byte Array

Tags: c#, arrays, memorystream

I am converting a image to a byte array, then converting the bytes into something my epson printer can print

this piece of code converts the picture into bytes fast

```
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        buff = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(signature, typeof(byte[]));
```

this one is slow but works

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte2(Image img)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            stream.Close();

            byteArray = stream.ToArray();
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
```

Both of these result in a different byte array and i can not figure out why, the memory stream one is the one that works for me but the conversion is slow

Can anyone perhaps hint as to why these bytes arrays are different converting the same picture

ex image converter byte array
[image: Image Converter]

ex memorystream conv

[image: Memorystream Conversion]

```
 string display = BitConverter.ToString(buff);

        MessageBox.Show(display);


Bitmap signature;
pictureBox1.Image=signature;
string Base64String = "79,27:79,27:79,26:79,26:79,26:79,27:79,28:77,30:73,33:69,38:66,44:62,52:56,62:48,72:42,79:39,82:39,81:#,#:79,29:79,29:78,28:80,26:82,26:81,30:77,36:75,40:74,44:75,47:76,50:78,51:84,48:92,41:101,33:108,27:110,26:109,26:109,28:109,30:109,31:109,34:107,40:103,49:97,58:93,65:88,71:87,74:#,#:133,38:133,38:133,38:132,40:129,47:124,54:121,59:117,65:114,70:#,#:130,39:130,39:130,39:135,35:145,29:157,24:166,23:#,#:125,52:125,52:122,53:125,52:136,48:147,47:152,48:#,#:114,69:114,69:112,69:117,68:129,65:139,63:147,62:#,#:199,30:199,30:197,31:196,35:195,40:195,45:191,54:182,63:174,72:171,76:173,76:182,72:198,69:216,67:231,66:239,66:240,67:238,68:#,#:";



        string[] cord = Base64String.Split(new Char[]{',',':'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Graphics g;

        g = Graphics.FromImage(signature);
        g.Clear(Color.White);

        Pen mypen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black));
        mypen.Width = 2;
        mypen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Square;
        mypen.StartCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.Square;
        mypen.MiterLimit = mypen.Width * 1.25f;
        mypen.LineJoin = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineJoin.Round;
        for (int i = 0; i < cord.Length; i=i+4)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(cord[i]);
            Point p;
            Point p2;
            if (cord[i] != "#" && cord[i + 1] != "#")
            {
                p = new Point(int.Parse(cord[i]), int.Parse(cord[i + 1]));


                if (cord[i + 2] != "#" && cord[i + 3] != "#")
                {
                    p2 = new Point(int.Parse(cord[i + 2]), int.Parse(cord[i + 3]));
                }
                else
                {
                    p2 = new Point(int.Parse(cord[i]), int.Parse(cord[i + 1]));

                }

            }
            else
            {

            }




        }

        g.Dispose();
        signature = BitmapTo1Bpp(signature);

public static Bitmap BitmapTo1Bpp(Bitmap img)
    {
        int w = img.Width;
        int h = img.Height;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(w, h, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
        BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
        byte[] scan = new byte[(w + 7) / 8];
        for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
            {
                if (x % 8 == 0) scan[x / 8] = 0;
                Color c = img.GetPixel(x, y);
                if (c.GetBrightness() >= 0.5) scan[x / 8] |= (byte)(0x80 >> (x % 8));
            }
            Marshal.Copy(scan, 0, (IntPtr)((long)data.Scan0 + data.Stride * y), scan.Length);
        }
        bmp.UnlockBits(data);
        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: message box for displaying byte array?

Comment: what is `signature`?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys signature is a bitmap that is displayed in a picturebox

Comment: Show us code how you initialize signature - if it is not bitmap (.png, .jpg, etc.) than it is working as expected - ImageConvert just yields direct byte[] representation of image, so if the backing image was not in .bmp format it won't be converted to bmp format.

Comment: @dotctor edit shows message box code

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar added all my code i use to draw my bitmap and display into a picture box then convert into a monochrome bitmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the MSDN documentation found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the ImageConverter function is converting the **internal** .NET representation of the image object reference to a byte array rather than the image data it contains.

Comment: your guess should be a comment

Comment: where the phrase "the ImageConverter function is converting the internal .NET representation of the image object reference to a byte array" is mentioned in that link?

Comment: The  override of ConvertTo comes from TypeConverter, which converts references. "Converts the given value object to the specified type, using the arguments. (Inherited from TypeConverter.)"

Comment: This makes sense is there a way to use this and allow it to convert the image data, if not i will keep searching memory stream takes about 7 seconds to convert to byte